# Security for REST interface, backend using Parse

Tags: rest, security, parse-platform

I am currently developing a mobile app that is using a REST interface to fetch and post data to and from the server. I changed each request to include a token from Parse that the server can verify. I am trying to implement HTTPS right now, but I am wondering what other security features should I include in my application to make sure the request is verified as the correct user. Any resources on the subject would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of some additional measures you can put in place.

- Don’t write the master key in the source codes of the clients. They don’t need it.
- Use ACL in your code.
- Use Parse Server 2.2.1 or above to enjoy CLP.
- Set enableAnonymousUsers to false which prevents anonymous calls to the API.
- Modify the `index.js` file to use the Allow Client Class Creation option. Disable at the production stage.

Over and above that you can also make use express-brute and other middleware packages. There are several packages on NPM that are dedicated to that